# Support for $links on a typeless web api odata v3 implementation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm implementing a typeless entity on web api odata. I'm having trouble implementing the $links.

Entity(Id)/$links/AnotherEntity

I think the odata.id property that is produced when using the $format=application/json;odata=fullmetadata is the one that is shown when you use the $links but when I tried to use the $select=odata.id it throws an error that the property is not part of the object.

Am i missing any property on the request or do I have to create a new serializer for this to be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

odata.id is auto-generated with fullmetadata.

You can't get it by $select.

You can only get it from the response payload or generate it yourself.